# VB6 (erk) - Inline functions?

Tags: vb6, inline-functions

I use VB6 for an application.

Is it possible to force the compiler to inline a function?

Or is there an add-in that achieves the same thing?

There's a secure part of my code that I want to make difficult to hack, by repeating the code at every point where it is used instead of being listed once as a function.

Hope someone can answer my question!

Answer (score 5):

IMO if this is what you're doing as a security measure, you have bigger problems than getting VB to inline your function.  And I don't think there is any provision in VB6 to do this.  AND I tend to think that this technique would make it easier to hack your code, since you'd see the same really important function repeated over and over again...  Sorry :-(

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for inlining a function. However there are several things working in your favor.

First VB6 is notoriously difficult to decompile as witness by the lack of decompilers on the market over the history. The results has been less than useful for people trying to recover lost source code or hack VB6.

But...

If you are using ActiveX DLLs then it could very easy to hack your software by a person writing a compatible DLL. The best way my company found to deal with this is to make critical objects public non-creatable and exchange packed binary data.

The public non-creatable prevents somebody from referencing the DLL, creating instance of that object and then running tests to see what you are doing. The binary data is to obscure the data you are exchanging.

In you look in the literature about COM there are more secure ways of dealing with these issues but these are simple things you can do to make a ActiveX application more difficult to hack.

My company goal isn't to make it impossible for somebody to hack our software but make it difficult enough that it cost less for our competitor to deal with us rather than try to hack our system (A CAD/CAM system)

Answer (score 2):

As Dave said there is no support for that in the VB compiler.

If you really want to this why not run a search & replace on a copy of your code and build that copy. Doing that on the command line shouldn't be too difficult.